# Problema dibujando CANVAS

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un error en mi código por el cual no me muestra mi dibujo. Si alguno me lo indica me ayudaría mucho:

```
var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
var lienzo = d.getContext("2d");
var lineas = 30;
var l = 0;
var yi;
var xf;

while(l < lineas)
{
    xf = 10 * l;
    yi = 10 * (l + 1);
    dibujarlinea ("pink", 0, y1, xf, 300);
    console.log("lineas " + l);
    l = l + 1;
}

dibujarlinea("#AFA", 1,1,1,300);

function dibujarlinea(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal)
{
    lienzo.beginPath();
    lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
    lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
    lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
    lienzo.stroke();
    lienzo.closePath();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes al ejecutar tu código?

Comment: no se me ejecuta el dibujo

Comment: Pero te arroja algún error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noto inconsistencia en esta línea

```
dibujarlinea ("pink", 0, y1, xf, 300);
```

creo debe ser

```
dibujarlinea ("pink", 0, yi, xf, 300);
```

ya que veo asi se llama tu variable

```
yi = 10 * (l + 1);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Me traia loco ese error tan pavo